# How to make a two-column page with a background img that scales in one of the columns?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, background-image

I want to create a two-column layout; one column (ca 70%) with a background image and one with a scroll bar(ca 30%).

I want both the background image and the scroll bar to resize/scale so that it follows the size of the browser window, but with the height of the background image always being the same as the browser window.

Comment: Hi signe, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is not appropriate for this site: this site is for questions about specific problems with specific coding jobs - but your question is asking for help with something you don't seem to even know how to start. I think you should look somewhere else for some basic introductions to html and css styling.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display:inline-block` to create two-column layout.And to keep background image size same as browser, you can do `background-size:cover`.

Note: Scroll in second column depends on the content of that column.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box1">box1</div>
<div class="box2">box2</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box1
{
display:inline-block;
width:70%;
background : url(url/to/image) no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

.box2
{
display:inline-block;
width:30%;
}
```

**Alternatively you can do the same with Bootstrap**.

you might not get exactly 70-30 ratio, but you can play with different options.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 box1 ">
        column1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        column2
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box1
{
background : url(url/to/image) no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Don't forget to include bootstrap in your code.